# Log4j hangs my application for few minutes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Unfortunately there is no much information available. We are using log4j for logging in an app and try to login some information in a loop. One iteration - one new write. That is what happens: all writes goes fine except one that take 3-4 minutes to be written. And it doesn't happen all the time in one place - there are other places in the program with the same behavior. It seems that log4j has some problems with free space or, maybe, some  deadlocks.

I know that it is not enough information to give a clear answer, but any advice would be great.

Can log4j cause problems that look like one described above?

Comment: are you logging to file system?

Comment: try profiling the application real time using something like YourKit, and see if that spots the problem

Comment: yes. all logs are in a .log file.

Comment: Did you do any String appending like costly operations in logging?
Can you post your code as we can see how you are using Logger.

Comment: Does the rest of the application hang at the same time as the big pause occurs in log writing? Could be you're looking at a symptom, not the cause.

Comment: To @epoch : unfortunately I cannot run application. Have no access.

Comment: To @Ruchi : I cannot post the code but I can assure you that there are no costly operations.

Comment: To @DaveHowes : Yes, the rest of application hangs at that time. But it happend a few times in that loop when we are logining (on different iterations). Do you think it may be a coincidence and smth else can hang an application? Now I believe that it is log4j internal issue.

Comment: If you are getting pauses that happen at arbitrary intervals, the first thing I would check would be the garbage collector. Can you turn verbose garbage collection on and see whether that explains these long pauses?

Answer (score 0):

If your question as i understood you face that problem because you let log4j launch it's configuration commands, so all you have to do is forbid it from doing that by using this piece of code :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
        loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
        for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
            logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        }
```